# Non-executable (NX) memory warning on an HP Proliant DL380 G5

Tags: cpu, bios, nx

I am getting the following warning message from a new installation of Ubuntu 10.04 (server version) on an HP Proliant DL380 G5:

```
Your CPU appears to be lacking expected security protections.

  $ /usr/bin/check-bios-nx --verbose
```

> gives me:

```
"This CPU is family 6, model 15, and has NX capabilities but is unable to
use these protective features because the BIOS is configured to disable
the capability"
```

> and:

```
$ grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | head -n1 | egrep --color=auto ' (pae|nx) '
gives me:
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr *pae* ....
```

The Security/CPUFeatures documentation  [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/CPUFeatures), states that, "the first flags line will include nx if the BIOS is not disabling the CPU feature, and the CPU is actually NX-capable"

To summarize so far, "nx" is not shown in the flags line from `/proc/cpuinfo`, whilst "pae", is...  Is there any documentation available or is anyone able to recommend a procedure for installing the "-server or -generic-pae flavor of the 32bit kernel"... and/or how to make the necessary adjustments to the BIOS.

Many thanks for putting up with this rather unwieldy question!

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>F9</kbd> while booting to enter the ROM-Based Setup Utiltiy.

- From System Options >> Processor Options choose "No-Execute Memory Protection".
- If it is „Disabled”, set it to „Enabled”.

Excerpt from the manual:

> No-Execute Memory Protection enables the hardware portion of a feature
>   that protects systems against malicious code and viruses. When used in
>   combination with an OS that supports this feature, certain memory is
>   marked as not for executable code. Viruses that attempt to insert and
>   execute code from non-executable memory locations are intercepted and
>   an exception is raised.
>
> Options include:
>
> - Enabled (default)
> - Disabled
>
> NOTE: When using virtualization operating systems such as VMware ESX/ESXi and Windows Hyper-V, be sure to enable this option.

Information source:

- [Manual](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00191707/c00191707.pdf)
- [HP ProLiant Servers - Updating the Server Firmware ROM Page](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodTypeId=5351&objectID=c00719376)